# Difference between using Prune function to tune the tree and set the tuned parameters in rpart

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart, rpart

When we found the tuned parameters(e.g. the CP or maxdepth), what is the difference between using Prune function to tune the tree and set the tuned parameters in rpart? 
i.e. What is the difference between
 `prune(tree,cp=best_cp,maxdepth=best_cp)` 
and put the tuned parameters back into the rpart 
`rpart(income~., data=train,cp=best_cp,maxdepth=best_cp)`

Since I tune the model using `prune` function, it has no improvement. While I put the tuned parameters back into the `rpart`,  it has a significant improvement.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example?